# How do I check, using terminal what sudo pip packages I've installed?

Tags: macos, terminal, pip, sudo

How do I check what sudo pip packages I've installed on my mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the usage:

```
$ pip

Usage:
  pip <command> [options]

Commands:
  install                     Install packages.
  download                    Download packages.
  uninstall                   Uninstall packages.
  freeze                      Output installed packages in requirements format.
  list                        List installed packages.
  show                        Show information about installed packages.
  check                       Verify installed packages have compatible dependencies.
  config                      Manage local and global configuration.
  search                      Search PyPI for packages.
  wheel                       Build wheels from your requirements.
  hash                        Compute hashes of package archives.
  completion                  A helper command used for command completion.
  help                        Show help for commands.
```

The one you want is `sudo pip list`.

Comment: Okay. Thanks! When ever I run sudo commands, I get a password requirement- why is that?

Comment: @Laythesmack Because you're trying to elevate your privileges to the root user, which requires a password.